# Verificar se várias colunas contem um valor?

Tags: c#, linq, expressões-lambda

## Query:

```
query = query.Where(t =>
                t.campo1.Contains(filter) || t.campo2.Contains(filter) || ......);
```

Gostaria de saber se tem alguma forma que não preciso ficar informando todos os campos da tabela, fazer algo mais genérico para realizar a busca.

Comment: Não entendi o porque disso, primeiro, porque essa consulta é ruim e se a pesquisa for feita em vários campos se poderia utilizar outra técnica fora do Entity Framework, agora se você precisa que seja todos campos não existe nada automático ou genérico, você precisa passar sim os campos e talvez isso seja uma única vez, sinceridade é assim mesmo que faz e se for fazer uma SQL pura, também vai ter que passar os campos, já penso nisso.???

Comment: Isto não usa EF ou outro ORM?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Você poderá buscar da seguinte maneira se os dados já estiverem materializados
Exemplo em https://dotnetfiddle.net/uSnmsJ:

```
query = query.Where(x => new[] { x.Campo1, x.Campo2, x.Campo3}.Any(s => s.Contains(filter)));
```

Para dados não materializados, ou seja, que serão recuperados por algum ORM (ex. NHibernate) talvez isso não funcione, pois ele irá converter para sql, faça o teste e informe. Busque todos os dados com um ToList() e faça a busca nos dados materializados. Se a tabela não for muito grande isso irá executar em um tempo aceitável.

Atualizei o exemplo em https://dotnetfiddle.net/uSnmsJ criando uma listafiltrada2 buscando por todos os atributos.

```
var listaFiltrada2 = lista.Where(m => m.GetType().GetProperties().Any(x => x.GetValue(m, null) != null && x.GetValue(m, null).ToString().Contains("Marco"))).ToList();
```

Comment: Teria alguma forma de  x.Campo1, x.Campo2, x.Campo3 ser altomatico, pois tenho uma tabela com muitas colunas e queia pesquisar em todas.

Comment: @LuizLanza acho que do jeito que estás pretendendo, apenas usando reflexão

Comment: @ArturoTemplário , atualizei o exemplo conforme você informou.

Comment: @MarcoAntonioQuintal ótimo, mas eu não sei se é uma boa ideia fazer assim, me parece muito estranho

Comment: @ArturoTemplário , também achei, acho melhor informar em que propriedade buscar, igual na lista1